# Using \textsc and \textbf with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, small-caps

I would like to have my section titles in bold and small caps, but they do not seem to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    left = 2cm, 
    right = 2.5cm, 
    top = 1.5cm, 
    bottom = 2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sc\bfseries}{}{0cm}{}[\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries\sc}{}{0cm}{}[ --]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\sc}{}{0cm}{}


\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\makebox[0pt][r]{--}}

%Manipulation of headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Clear fields
\fancyhf{}
%Page numbering in footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%Separation line header and footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{\textsc{Eating\hspace{0.5cm}Foods}}
\end{center}

\section{How to eat food}
Food is important
\subsection{Using hands}
Most versatile
\subsection{using chopsticks}
Requires practice
\subsection{using spoons}
Kind of a middle ground
\subsubsection{Types of spoons}
There are many types of spoons

\end{document}
```

Currently, all titles only come in bold font or small caps depending on their order of appearance in the \titleformat argument.

Comment: Two letter font commands are deprecated (use `\scshape` instead of `\sc`) which accounts for the ordering issue. See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361). But the problem simply is that most fonts don't contain a bold small caps series. If you check the log file you will see font substitution warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alan Munn mentioned in the comments, you need to use `\scshape` rather than the plain TeX `\sc` (which cannot be combined with other formatting).  You will then get the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
```

OT1 is the original 7-bit TeX encoding from the ’80s (back when network hardware would often use the eighth bit for error correction and mangle 8-bit data).  It’s still the default output encoding in PDFTeX (although the default input encoding is now UTF-8).  The default font, Computer Modern Roman (`cmr`), doesn’t define a bold extended (`bx`) small-caps (`sc`) face in OT1.

In PDFTeX, you can fix this by switching to a slightly-less-obsolete 8-bit encoding from the ’90s.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If you can, I would recommend changing to LuaLaTeX and modern fonts.  The default font in LuaLaTeX does not come in bold small-caps either, but you can switch to a clone that does, such as New Computer Modern.  (The settings I used will get you a slightly-heavier font, but you can tweak this if you want with a package option.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage[
    left = 2cm, 
    right = 2.5cm, 
    top = 1.5cm, 
    bottom = 2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bfseries}{}{0cm}{}[\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries\scshape}{}{0cm}{}[ --]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\scshape}{}{0cm}{}


\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\makebox[0pt][r]{--}}

%Manipulation of headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Clear fields
\fancyhf{}
%Page numbering in footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%Separation line header and footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{\textsc{Eating\hspace{0.5cm}Foods}}
\end{center}

\section{How to eat food}
Food is important
\subsection{Using hands}
Most versatile
\subsection{using chopsticks}
Requires practice
\subsection{using spoons}
Kind of a middle ground
\subsubsection{Types of spoons}
There are many types of spoons

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another easy option for a font with bold small caps would be [Linux Libertine](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/linuxlibertine/), which can be used by simply loading `\usepackage{libertine}`, in case one does not want to use LuaLaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @shekura Yes. I believe that package also sets the T1 encoding.

Comment: It seems that the `newcomputermodern` font does not play well with the amsmath package(s)

Comment: @Raven `newcomputermodern` loads `unicode-math`, which loads `amsmath`. Loading `amsmath` with different options ought to work if you load it before `newcomputermodern` and `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Raven But, what problem were you having?

Comment: Ah okay then maybe that was the issue. I got a bunch of error messages that seemingly came from the amsmath package but I included them _after_ `newcomputermodern`. Thanks for pointing this out.